Sieving in the Gaussian integers
Can anyone provide any references - lecture notes, books, expositions, blogs - about sieving in number fields? I'm specifically interested in the Gaussian moat problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_moat.
The only resource I can find is Chapter 11 of Harman's "Prime-detecting sieves" (which is great, I'd just like more resources as well).
